# How do i know notification send to firebase or not

Tags: laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

i want to send notification to specific android device with laravel-firebase . currently i am following this  "brozot/laravel-fcm" so when Sending a Downstream Message to a Device , how do i know notification is send or not . when i test it in my postman it returns

```
LaravelFCM\Response\DownstreamResponse Object
(
[numberTokensSuccess:protected] => 0
[numberTokensFailure:protected] => 1
[numberTokenModify:protected] => 0
[messageId:protected] =>
[tokensToDelete:protected] => Array
(
[0] => .....
)

[tokensToModify:protected] => Array
(
)

[tokensToRetry:protected] => Array
(
)

[tokensWithError:protected] => Array
(
)

[hasMissingToken:protected] =>
[tokens:LaravelFCM\Response\DownstreamResponse:private] => Array
(
[0] => .....
)

[logEnabled:protected] =>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the response how many messages succeeded or failed.  From your own output above:

```
[numberTokensSuccess:protected] => 0
[numberTokensFailure:protected] => 1
```

It looks like you tried to send a message to one device, and it failed.